# No template for Azure for visual studio 2012?

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2012

I installed Azure SDK for Visual Studio 2012 Professional, but I don't see any template for Cloud projects.  My intallation succeeded without any errors.  Any ideas?

Comment: @ShahinDohan - in the future, you should post as an answer, not as a comment (unless you're merely commenting on the question). This allows people to vote it up and mark it as an answer.

Comment: @DavidMakogon - Yeah, I'm not really sure why I even answered in the comment section. Moved it now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to install the Windows Azure SDK together with the Visual Studio Tools for Windows Azure (these are not included in a clean VS2012 installation).

There's a complete installer on the official Windows Azure site which contains everything you need: https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/ (the big install button).

Comment: I did install it from there, but the no template for .NET Framework 4.5.  If I select .NET framework 4.0, I do see a template for Cloud!

Comment: At the moment .NET Framework 4.5 is not supported. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985654/net-4-5-rtm-on-azure/11985991#11985991

Answer (score 3):

You need to pick .NET Framework 4 from the little dropdown box at the top, since 4.5 is selected by default and is not supported by Azure yet.